# Awk/Cut variable denying further use of mutt?

Tags: bash, awk, cut, mutt

So I am building a script to check for files with certain errors in a bunch of files, based on output from an SQL DB. The file with the error shall be sent to me via mail.

The problem is that when I try to send the mail, I get the message 
"script.sh: 9: mutt: not found" Which does not occur, if I send the mail before the PATH variable is created.

The script looks as following:

```
JOB=$(sudo cat /tmp/sqltest.txt | awk '{ print $5 }')
DATE=$(sudo cat /tmp/sqltest.txt | awk '{ print $1 }')
CODE=$(sudo cat /tmp/sqltest.txt | awk '{ print $3 }')
PATH=$(grep ${CODE} /tmp/unzip/* | awk '{ print $1 }' | cut -d':' -f1 | head -n 1)
echo "File containing error message for job "${JOB}" at "${DATE}"" | mutt -a "/tmp/sqltest.txt" -s "Mail title" -- <mail@address>
```

In short, grep finds the file where the error code is, awk picks out the column with the path to the file, the column also comes with a timestamp which cut removes and head ensures that I only get one result, if the error is reported several places.

I can send the mail with mutt if I use it after variable CODE, instead of PATH, though I unfortunately need PATH instead of /tmp/sqltest.txt

Do you have any ideas on what might cause this?

Comment: This is probably running outside of command line context.  If the mutt executable lives in /usr/bin, then /usr/bin/mutt is the command you want, not just plain mutt

Comment: It's in /usr/bin/
What makes it weird to me is that it stops working after setting the PATH variable. Works if I put it just before.
Also, it works if I fire the line straight from the terminal. With and without adding /usr/bin before

Comment: That is what was meant by 'command line context'.  And changing PATH is probably just what is breaking it. Please post the output of echo $PATH when the script does not work.  Put the echo command IN the script.  Just for now.  Please note: The simplest script change is what I suggested: /usr/bin/mutt

Comment: Change the line setting the PATH to `PATH=$(grep ${CODE} /tmp/unzip/* | awk '{ print $1 }' | cut -d':' -f1 | head -n 1):${PATH}`

Comment: That seemed to do it, devnull.
Would you please post it as an answer? I would like to upvote for this one. Also, could you give a description of what's happening with the part you added? I haven't used it myself before.
EDIT:
Changing the file I wanted to attach to the mail to ${PATH} gave me the following error: Can't stat /tmp/unzip/File.log:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games: No such file or directory

Comment: Hold on a second : are you actually trying to use `PATH` as a "normal" variable, lets say like you will do with `PATH2`?

Comment: Yeah, that seemed to be it. Yet again, I fall for the low trick of predetermined variables.

Comment: In general, don't use all caps for *your* variables: [the shell's variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Variables) are generally uppercase, and as you've learned, you don't want to inadvertently override those.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we got here is a classic case of trying to use an environment variable (and a pretty important one !) : just use another variable name to get rid of the error. As some suggested, it is good practice to try to avoid full-uppercase variables.

***Environment Variables***
There is a couple of environment variables inside Bash, `PATH` being one of it.
You can get the list of both environment and shell variables using the `set` command.

***Source*** : 
[Environment Variable on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Unix)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the output obtained by command substitution to the `PATH`.

Change the line setting the PATH to

> PATH=$(grep ${CODE} /tmp/unzip/* | awk '{ print $1 }' | cut -d':' -f1
>   | head -n 1):${PATH}

The change in PATH would be valid for the duration of the script.